# Replacing an entire observation/character string if it contains specific characters

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of providers who offer a particular course according to CEFR levels (The Common European Framework of Reference for Languages), of which there should be 6 (*A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2*)

The database was compiled by many different people, so the text inputs are not all quite the same. This means that instead of 6 factors I had 61.

I tried changing the data frame class so that all observations are characters, and then replace observations containing the target expression and excess characters (in this case "A1") with the target expression and no white space.

I am using the **stringr** package.

```
str_replace_all(ilepString$Entry.Level, "A1", "NA_Character_")
str_replace_all(ilepString$Entry.Level, "NA", "A1")
str_trim(ilepString$Entry.Level)
str_detect(ilepString$Entry.Level, "A1") #This shows me that I have failed, quite miserably, as character strings containing solely "A1" are in data obs., but entries of "A1" along with other unwanted characters, or blank space, still persist in the dataset.
```

I have also tried the following;

gsub(".*A0.*", "A1", ilepString$Entry.Level)

However, when I ask to see how the data looks now with

```
  dput(head(ilepString$Entry.Level))

c("", "A1", "A1", "A2", "B1", "B2")
#Looking at the head, the output seems fine, but the following command shows the problem remains:

    ilepString$Entry.Level[351:369] 
[351] "A1-B1"                    "A2"                      
[353] "B1"                       "A2-B2"                   
[355] "4.5 A2"                   "B1"                      
[357] "B2"                       "A1-A2"                   
[359] "A2-B1"                    "A2-B2"                   
[361] "A1"                       "A2"                      
[363] "B1"                       "B2"                      
[365] "A1"                       "A2"                      
[367] "B1"                       "B2"                      
[369] " A1"                      " A2"
```

I want each Entry/obs. to be reduced to just a single Letter and Number.

```
[351] "A1"                       "A2"                      
[353] "B1"                       "A2"                   
[355] "A2"                       "B1"                      
[357] "B2"                       "A1"                   
[359] "A2"                       "A2"
```

My apologies if I have explained myself quite badly.
Please bear in mind that I am quite new at `R`, and don't really have much of a  clue  at all.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the output from `dput(head(ilepString))` so we can help more quickly? Also, what does "I have failed, quite miserably" mean? did you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

What you're running into is that gsub and str_replace_all find the pattern within a string and replace the pattern with your new string within the existing string. Those functions as far as I know don't support entire string replacement.

Example:

```
str_replace("Hi my name is Zach", "Zach", "John") 
[1] "Hi my name is John"
```

So instead for a problem like this, I'd suggest either using str_detect to find which observations you need to do a complete replacement with like this (Note: this overwrites the existing data and can be modified to be a new column instead):

```
ilepString$Entry.Level[str_detect(ilepString$Entry.Level, "A1")] = "A1"
```

Or another approach I'd suggest looking into for problems like this is string matching with the *stringdist* package. The function *amatch* matches a string based on a similarity measure (there a number of supported metrics for amatch) to a pre-determined set.

An example by the author of the package can be found here:

- http://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2013/08/09/approximate-string-matching-in-r/

Essentially for your problem you'd be writing a statement like this:

```
amatch(ilepString$Entry.Level, c('A1','A2','B1','B2','C1','C2')...other inputs...)
```

I hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks zcoleman. Perfectly simple and obvious idea, I never really got. As preposterous as it sounds it just didn't cross my mind to pull the strings that I was looking for out and just make a new column!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want.
But I assume you want to replace certain string patterns with specific patterns.
For example, the code below can replace "A0" with "A1".

I hope this helps.

```
numSample = 4
set.seed(5)
df = data.frame("levelOriginal" = paste0(
  sample(x = c("A","B","C"), size = numSample, replace = TRUE),
  floor(runif(n = numSample, min = 0, max = 3))
), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$levelRevised = df$levelOriginal
df$levelRevised[grepl(pattern = "A0", x = df$levelRevised)] = "A1"

df
# levelOriginal levelRevised
# 1            A0           A1
# 2            C2           C2
# 3            C1           C1
# 4            A2           A2
```